# Use of matlab "overlayVolume" display

Tags: image, matlab, volume

I'm working on volumes, i have a mask and a CTMEP . The mask allows to locate the tumour. 
At first, i wanted to find a way to overlay my two volumes so that i found that : 
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/39460-overlayvolume/content/overlayVolume.m .

I tried but i'm not satisfied of my 3 figures that appear. 
As a matter of fact, the display is too dark , and i can't distinguish the differents part of the organs. I don't know which parameter i have to modify to see my organs. I thought at the begining that it was because i was in HU but even in greyscale i can't see anything. I add a picture of what i see.

Thank you for your help.

here is the link.

[image]

Comment: I can not see the picture in tinypic. Try Imgur.

Comment: http://imgur.com/yWpUOpO. Is it better ? By the way, what you will see in grey in the middle must be the tumour ie the mask !

Comment: Brilliant. Can you also post the code of how you are plotting this? Most likely the problem is the range. What datatipe is your grayscale image, and what is its max/min?

Comment: To plot that, i just use the "overlayVolume" function that i put as a link in my presentation. It takes two volumes and plot 3 figures. As you may see in the link, i can modify the range. I didin't do that, i let the default parameters. Let me see what are the min/max values. :)

Comment: Hm the minValue is 0 , the maxValue is 4071 !

Comment: Try saving a new image that is calculated as `Inew=double(Imold)./max(Imold(:))`, and the using that one

Comment: http://imgur.com/KD3hjBM I think it's way better now, thank you ! May i know why? I guess the reason is something about the bits or ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on how the plotting function is called inside the `overlayVolume`.

When you use `imshow(I)` it behaves differently for different types of data.

If your data is `uint8` `imshow` will assume that it is in range 0-255. If your data is `uint16` it will assume it is 0-65535. This means that it will plot white for 65535 and black for 0.

If your data is double, `imshow(I)` will assume it is in range 0-1 (so converting an image to double and dividing by its max value will plot it correctly).

What happens in your case is that you are dealing with X-ray images. Generally , in this type of data, you need the values stored in `uint16` type due to the resolution you need, but you generally do not use the whole range because the images are created by mathematical algorithms. Your max value was `4071`, wich is way closer to black (0) than it is to white (65535) so almost everything was plotted in black or dark grey. Converting it to double and putting it in the range 0-1 solved the problem.

If the function `imshow()` wasn't inside a class someone else created but you where putting it in your code my suggestion would be different. `imshow` accepts ranges as input, so you could do `imshow(I,[0 4071])` to force 4071 to be "white". More generally you could do`imshow(I,[min(I(:) max(I(:)])`, or the equivalent call (and less verbose) `imshow(I,[])`.